# How to execute the custom action in silent mode in wix?

Tags: wix, custom-action

I am trying to execute the custom action at the time of uninstall the installer in wix.It is working perfectly but it is showing the splash screen of cmd prompt at the time of custom action.Latter I tried with CAQuietExec but it is unable to uininstall the installer and giving error.
(CAQuietExec: Error 0x80070057: failed to get command line data).

The command that I am using is :

```
<Fragment>
<Property Id="ModifyOutlookRegInitSign_14" Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]reg.exe&quot; ADD &quot;HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security&quot; /v InitSign /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"/>
    <CustomAction Id="ModifyOutlookRegInitSign_14" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
                Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="ModifyOutlookRegInitSign_14" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is an immediate custom action, the name of the property containing the command line as value must have an `Id="QtExecCmdLine"`. For other types of custom actions read [Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html).

Comment: If I replace the immediate with deferred , it is giving same error.

Comment: Of course. For a deferred custom action you need to add additional steps and name it otherwise. You can find it in the provided link [Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html). Did you rename the `Id`-attribute of your property to `QtExecCmdLine`? It **has** to be named like this for an immediate CA.

Comment: Here my requirement is to define multiple custom actions.How can I place multiple commands in QtExecCmdLine property value ?. So I am using Execute=deferred so that I can define property Id as different for different custom action. But it is giving the error like above.

Comment: In this case you have to schedule another custom action of type 51 (set a property with formatted text) before the next cmd-CA to set the property to the new command line. Note that for deferred custom actions you have to name it differently and, depending if you have properties within your command line, you also need another CA. See the link posted above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to update HKCU during the uninstall.  This is probably because Windows Installer doesn't natively support the ability to do so.

But your proposed solution is lacking in several way.  Mainly that it doesn't support rollback and doesn't support cleaning up other user profiles.

Did this registry entry had to be implemented in HKCU?  Could it be implemented in HKLM?

Comment: Update HKCU during uninstall is working as normal custom action. If I am trying to do that in silent mode it is giving error (CAQuietExec: Error 0x80070057: failed to get command line data).

Comment: The error is pointing to this direction: it cannot find the property `QtExecCmdLine` containing the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a custom action to kill a process silently like this:

```
<!-- WixQuietExecCmdLine specify the cmd to be executed -->
<Property Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value='"[WindowsFolder]System32\TaskKill.exe" /F /T /IM MyApp.exe'/>

<!-- From WiX v3.10, use WixQuietExec -->
<CustomAction Id="MyAppTaskKill" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore"/>

<!-- trigger the custom action -->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='MyAppTaskKill' Before='InstallValidate'></Custom>  
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

You have more info about the possible configuration combinations here: 
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your custom action around a Property with Id set to **WixQuietExecCmd.**

```
<Property Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value="command line to run"/>
```

[WiX Property Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/property.html)

[WiX Quiet Execution of Custom Action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html)